# Date() is showing error regarding mismatched parameters

Tags: java, date, datetime

i have tried these lines in my code

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
String formattedDate = df.format(new Date());
out.println(formattedDate);
```

But Date() is showing some error like no suitable constructor found for Date() and constructor Date.Date(long) is not applicable(actual and formal argument list differ in length). I have searched alot but didnt found any answer. I just want a date in simple format. Help !!
I tried giving a argument like

```
String formattedDate=df.format(new Date(0));
```

but it displayed a date like 1/1/70.

Comment: Did you import `java.sql.Date` instead of `java.util.Date`?

Comment: yes i had imported it

Comment: You imported what? `java.sql.Date`? If yes this is not the one you want.

Comment: oh that was the problem..i imported java.sql.Date instead of java.util.date . Now it works fine . Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must have imported wrong `Date` class, Make sure you `import java.util.Date;`

Comment: After re-reading the question I think this is correct. You might also want to consider using `Calendar.getInstance().getTime()`

Answer (score 0):

You must check that you import the correct package in the correct way of jsp file.
**`<%@ page import="java.util.Date" %>`** in the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )
         .format( 
             DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.SHORT )
                              .withLocale( Locale.CANADA )
         )
```

For January 23, 2016:

> 23/01/16

See [live code in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/C8V6tU).

## java.time

The accepted [Answer by Joshi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23596241/642706) is correct.

Also, the modern way to do this is with the java.time classes that supplant the troublesome old legacy date-time classes.

### `DateTimeFormatter`

The [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html?is-external=true) class can automatically localize when creating a string that represents a date-time value. Your desired format happens to be that of dates localized to Canada and [other locales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country).

You can specify a custom format if desired. Usually better to let java.time localize.

To localize, specify:

- [`FormatStyle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) to determine how long or abbreviated should the string be.
- [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to determine (a) the human language for translation of name of day, name of month, and such, and (b) the cultural norms deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, and such.

Example code:

```
Locale l = Locale.CANADA ;
DateTimeFormatter f = 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.SHORT )
                     .withLocale( l ) ;
```

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

To generate a string representing this date value in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, call `toString`.

```
String outputStandard = today.toString();
```

> 2016-01-23

To generate a string representing this date value, call [`format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#format-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-).

```
String output = today.format( f );
```

> 23/01/16

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score -2):

I had this problem. If you are on Netbeans right click the page then select fix

imports, then change `import java.sql.date;` to `import java.util.date;` if you

have auto save on. Below is the complete program to print current date and to

format the current date

import java.util.Date; //don't use java.sql.date here it is a subset of java

//util.date and if you don't import this it won't work.

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import java.text.DateFormat;

public class DateFormat
{

public static void main(String[] args)

{

//java.util.Date jdate = new java.util.Date();

String Billdate = "dd-MM-yyyy";

DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(Billdate);

Date dt=new Date();  //current date

```
 System.out.println("The current date is="+dt); 

System.out.println("The Formatted current date
```

is="+sdf.format(dt.getTime()));

}
}

Comment: It is important to add import statement for date if this happens. It mus specifically be import java.util.date. If you don't use it or use import java.sql.date; it may show error

Comment: import java.util.Date; //imports date class
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.DateFormat;

public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    
                                    String Billdate = "dd-MM-yyyy";
                                    DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(Billdate);
    Date dt=new Date();  //current date
    
   
    
    System.out.println("The Formatted current date is="+sdf.format(dt.getTime())); 

  }
}

Comment: You don't need to repeat an already given answer. Stack Overflow is a Q&A site where everyone can cleanly vote each other on (dis)agreement/confirmation, not like an old fashioned discussion forum wherein everyone repeats each other into an undigestable/unsearchable mess upon (dis)agreement/confirmation.